# System.OutOfMemoryException When Compiling Code With a COM Component in 32 bit and Using On a 64 bit System

Tags: c#, .net, com, 32bit-64bit

My code works fine on a 32 bit system.  I am simply referencing a COM component that reads/writes xml.  So, I tried compiling in 'X86' and then running on a 64 bit system when I received the error below.

The following exception occurred:  System.OutOfMemoryException: Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {59D5FDED-B01B-47F4-BBBC-56941A2F4873} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 8007000e.

Comment: Can you post the interface you used? There's a good chance that it's using `int` or another datatype with the wrong size for a pointer somewhere.

Comment: Also, why are you using a COM component to write XML when there's a whole .NET namespace dedicated to processing XML?

Comment: This is a major server application that's been around for 10+ years.  It needs to be deployed on a 64 bit server.  I use the .NET namespace for all of my XML needs now.

Comment: There isn't an error in the code.  I'm simply creating a 'Query' object, then initializing, and setting an xml transaction.  I then read the id and site fields.  It's only four lines of code and works on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: This is reported as a Windows error (error #14) translated to managed exception type OOM.  Hard to guess where it comes from but this is typically an error generated by the Windows loader.  Something going wrong when the DLL gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Random suggestions:

- Attach debugger as native and see if there are interesting native exceptions.
- Try to make your exe "not large memory space aware".
- Verify if app loads as 32 bit one.
- Try to create the component with native code to verify it is properly installed on the system.

Note: if your COM component uses MSXML to work with XML loading it into managed application is not supported due to incomaptibilities between memory management. It is unlikely to be cause problem you are seeing, but more for general reference.

Comment: Have to agree with this approach. There's a chance that any COM component will have been written way before people had to think about 64-bit issues. All they have to have done is assume a pointer is 4 bytes wide, and it'll break on 64-bit machines. This may be a good time to move away from the COM component and use a purely managed solution.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was happening because the C++ COM Component was calling a C# library and not handling the exception it raised.